# SQL loop executes but new old values are over written

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As my question title says, my program loops but all of my values I updated are being overwritten. Here's the code posted below. Say `minRownum` is 1 and max is 12, I see the loop execute 12 times correctly and min gets updated +1 each time. But in the end result, only the final row in my column whose RowNum is 12 have any values

I'm not exactly sure why overwriting is occurring since I'm saying "Update it where the rownumber = minrownumber" then I increment minrownum.

Can anyone point to what I am doing wrong? Thanks

```
 WHILE (@MinRownum <= @MaxRownum)
    BEGIN
        print ' here' 
        UPDATE #usp_sec
        set amount=(
        SELECT sum(amount) as amount   
        FROM dbo.coverage
        inner join dbo.owner
        on coverage.api=owner.api
        where RowNum=@MinRownum
        );

        SET @MinRownum = @MinRownum + 1

    END
```

PS: I edited this line to say (below) and now every value has the same wrong number (its not distinct but duplicated to all.

```
        set amount = (SELECT sum(amount) as amount   
                      FROM dbo.coverage
                      INNER JOIN dbo.owner ON coverage.api = owner.api
where RowNum=@MinRownum
                     ) WHERE RowNum = @MinRownum;
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo. #usp_sec
(
RowNum int,
amount numeric(20,2),
discount numeric(3,2)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[handler](
    [recordid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [covid] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [ownerid] [char](10) NULL
)   

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[coverage](
    [covid] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [api] [char](12) NULL,
    [owncovid] [numeric](12, 0) NULL,
    [amount] [numeric](14, 2) NULL,
    [knote] [char](10) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[owner](
    [api] [char](12) NOT NULL,
    [owncovid] [numeric](12, 0) NULL,
    [ownerid] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [officer] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [appldate] [date] NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: why not do `UPDATE #usp_sec SET amount=sumamount FROM (SELECT sum(amount),RowNum as sumamount FROM dbo.coverage inner join dbo.owner ON coverage.api=owner.api Group By RowNum) as tmp ON tmp.RowNum = #usp_sec.RowNum WHERE #usp_sec.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 12`

Comment: The first thing you are doing wring is doing it in a loop at all. Never do inserts,updates or deletes in a loop.

Comment: @HLGEM what do you propose

Comment: Hmm, still no obvious connect between these tables and your temp table.  Could you describe what it is you are trying to accomplish with this?  And what is RowNum supposed to represent?

Comment: @RBarryYoung each row in coverage can be associated with a row/multiple in owner. the value of amount in coverage is 15. and this owner can be divided by 3 so 5 will be in each row in owner. I was attempting to select everyrow in coverage, in that same row, select how much from that 15 in amount is assigned to rows in owner. RowNum was added cause I was thinking that I could use it to identify and work with one row at a time. select the sum of amount where the join is true and update it where RowNum=1 (we are on the first row) then increment it an so on and so on

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use a loop to issue an UPDATE statement, as HLGEM said.  But we can't deal with any of that until you explain, simply and clearly, what relationship your temp table has with the others.  Are you trying to have one row per owner?  one row per year?  Obviously you have some logic in mind, so please share it.  If necessary, post some sample data for your tables. A SQL Fiddle would be even better.

Answer (score 3):

Your `UPDATE` statement needs its own `WHERE` clause.  Otherwise, each `UPDATE` will update every row in the table.

And the way you have this written, your subquery still needs its `WHERE` clause too.  In fact, you need to definitively correlate the subquery to your table's (#usp_sec) rows.  We cannot tell you how that should be done without more information such as your table definitions.

Comment: Young ive actually tried that "in my update" and one value gets duplicated for all the rows

Comment: @user3637951 Read the second paragraph.  You still need to correlate the subquery to the main table.

Comment: I have added the structure of the temp table, however i am not exacrtlly sure of the meaning to correlate the subquery. could you expound a bit please

Comment: @user3637951, execute your subquery by itself: you'll see that it's summing the amount of every single record, which is why you're getting "the same wrong number" in every row on the temp table. You have to identify which records in Coverage and Owner tie to a specific row in your temp table - what is the link between the two?

Comment: oh, indeed. coverage.api & owner.api is supposed to link, but I was attemping a stored proc without passing in parameters. this is why I was trying to associate the variable on @minnumrow WITH the row number. and then increment the variable so it would move to the next row...hmmmm

Comment: @user3637951 Its coverage and owner table definitions we need to see, to try to connect them to your temp table correctly.

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and edit your original post - include the code that goes into creating the temp table, and how that temp table is related to Coverage & Owner.  Without that link, there's no way to tie the sum of specific Amounts to a single row in the temp table.

Comment: updated. I also added a table which I think may be helpful to show linking